# How to link to an unspecified boost version

Tags: c++, dynamic, boost, ld

When I link against the boost library (Using Gentoo Linux), it always links to a very specific version of boost:

```
$ g++ -o foo foo.cpp -lboost_filesystem
$ ldd foo
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffadfff000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 (0x00002aafdf05b000)
...
```

The problem is that if other people want to use my program 'foo', they need the same version of boost or they will get linking errors. It doesn't seem like this is the correct behavior. When I add `-lboost_filesystem` it should link to `libboost_filesystem.so`, not to `libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0`.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Shared library linking should be transparent for compatible versions.

Comment: If you need to link with a specific version, link a static library.

Comment: It would help if you please show what symbolic links exist for `boost_filesystem` in `/usr/lib64/`, perhaps with `ls -la /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem*`?

Comment: You should really link to the versioned one, as different versions will be incompatible and if you linked against them, something will break.